# Kirchhoff's law for magnetic circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics, electromagnetic, magnetic-flux

I have been working on this problem:

[image]

The way I approached this problem is given (I used Kirchhoff's laws on Electrical equivalent of magnetic circuit) :

[image]

I have two doubts here:

1. My working does not give the right answer, can someone tell the mistake in my solution?
2. As per the book's solution, "Total ampere turns is equal to that required for path E and that required for two paths C or D".

Can someone explain this?

PS: If my solution is not clear due to handwriting or other issues, please contact me by commenting, I shall explain you my method.

Comment: No, I don't see figure 6.35. Put yourself in the reader's shoes.

Comment: @Andyaka It's a typo I guess, because that's what is given.

Comment: If you want this answered by someone (given that I have now unsuccessfully tried to decode your handwriting), I suggest you present the question in your own "typed" words with the relevant information and use properly formatted equations in mathjax. For instance, to make this example formula: \$L = \dfrac{N\cdot I}{\Phi}\$ requires you to type this `\$L = \dfrac{N\cdot I}{\Phi}\$`. You might also explain how the text in the first picture can possibly suggest that the MMF in C and D are the same. I disagree with that but, realistically, I've spent enough time on this so now.

Comment: I will try to write in MathJax, by the way do you agree with the book's claim that "MMF in C and D "are same? @Andyaka

Comment: I don't agree with it; the reluctances are different from the point of view of the MMF source.

Comment: I'm guessing it actually says the m.m.f. ACROSS paths C and D is the same.

Comment: @Andyaka the middle and the right limb are in parallel. Like voltage on parallel branches is the same, the m.m.f. (or anything you call flux multiplied by reluctance) is also the same.

Comment: @AlexVB so basically you are saying they both have the same flux

Comment: @Andyaka no, the reluctance is different. Flux is like current, reluctance is like resistance. One path is 15cm and another is 25cm. Shorter path gets more flux.

Comment: Well here’s where we might differ. I take path C to be the vertical middle section and path D to be the vertical right section I.e. they have the same length. The fact that we don’t agree on the relative lengths of these two paths is because the diagram is ambiguous. I gave up on this question hours ago so, solve it yourself please. I know what reluctance, MMF and flux is btw.